# gitでワーキングツリー上のファイルの内容を表示したい

Tags: git

表題の通りです。

`git show HEAD:<file>`でHEADでのファイルの内容を表示できることと，`git show :<file>`でインデックスでのファイルの内容を表示できることは分かったのですが，ワーキングツリー上での内容を見る方法はありませんか？

`less <file>`などで見れることは重々承知ですが，諸事情によりgitのコマンドとして実現したいのです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ワーキングツリーとは、要するにただのファイルシステムです。ファイルシステム上の特定のファイルを表示したい以上に、やりたいことがあるのでしょうか。どうして git のコマンドにしたいのでしょうか。

Comment: lessコマンドやWindowsならtypeコマンドで取得することに何の問題もないのですが，gitのコマンドを駆使して同じことができたらうれしいなぐらいです。あと，gitがファイルの内容をどのように解釈しているか(改行コードやキャリッジリターンの違いは無視するなど)を正確に取り出したいという意思があります。

Comment: git のコマンドで完結させるメリットは、unix と Windows で同じコマンドで実行したいからでしょうか。自分の知る限りでは、 git は unix 的な環境じゃないと動かないので(msysとか)、 unix コマンドを想定してもいいような… また、改行コード変換などが git によろしく取り扱われる件ですが、この変換はインデックス <-> ワークツリー の間で実行されます。ワークツリーは、git 的にはただのファイルシステムなはずなので、仮にこの内容を表示するコマンドがあったとしても、やりたいことは実現できないのでは、と思っています。

Comment: なるほどgitが行う各種変換はインデックス <-> ワークツリーで行われるとするとあまりgitのコマンドでやるメリットはないですね。とりえあえず @yukihane さんの`git-grep`を使う方法でやりたいことは実現できています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git-grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)で全行マッチさせるというのはどうでしょうか。

`git grep -h -e '' <file>`

Comment: おお，まさにこれです。うまく行きました。この方法はパフォーマンス的にも問題ないでしょうか？